# After transferring opportunity ownership and checking send notification email checkbox notification email is getting sent twice

Tags: apex, opportunity, ownership, sales-cloud

When I am changing owner of opportunity that time when send notification email checkbox is checked then new owner gets notification twice.
there is no any process builder or workflow which triggers it.
please help,

Answer (score 0):

Check all the workflow or Process builder which are responsible for sending the notification email. 
Or check your condition if it has **OR** condition than there might be some chances that it will get triggered twice. 
And best way to find out is to check the debug logs. There you can check and find if it is trigger twice. 
if possible can you post whatever you have done so far?

Comment: I have checked by deactivating all the  WF and PB, still its sending 2 emails, 
And its sending standard email template so no dought on WF and PB.

Comment: are you using salesforce community. because once I had the same issue where user was getting 2 emails same time. one was triggering from community. may be you can check there as well

Comment: No, I am not using community